# Emboss needle() warning: "Sequence Character not found in ajSeqCvtKS" ...?

Tags: warnings, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta, sequence-alignment

**I am using EMBOSSwin's needle() command line function which performs pairwise global alignments, but I encounter a strange warning.**

So I have 24 pairs of amino acid sequences that need aligning, I run the needle() command from python using "subprocess.call()" - whilst this process occurs (seemingly smoothly) I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Sequence character string not found in ajSeqCvtKS
```

***EXTRA CLUES:***

Albeit this strange warning... alignments are successfully generated by needle() in .fasta format as you can see...

[image: Needle() alignments seem fine, but the unexplained warning may explain errors I am getting downstream]

... ***BUT***... I am getting unexplained *"AssertionErrors"* when trying to read these alignments back into python - using biopython's AlignIO.read() function (see: http://bit.ly/1aHK9w7 for my question directly related to this *AssertionError*)...

*To be clear: these AlignIO() *AssertionErrors* **may not be related** to the needle() warning, but I am treating the warning as a *prime lead* in the investigation...!

Comment: Did the new emboss version also answer this question?

Comment: Very good point, well I suppose it has answered it to some level - in fact I suppose this question here is rather redundant now? Do you think I should delete it?

Comment: Well if it's solved, answer it yourself stating that the problem was the old version. Maybe someone else has the same problem.

Comment: well actually... I never worked out what the warning meant - what I meant by "answered it to some level" was that I updated the software and I never got the message again!